# Using AMQP with JTA

Tags: java, amqp, jta

Are there any good examples of using AMQP client in CMT/JTA environment? I know that AMQP supports transactional messaging, but I don't know how it aligns with JTA.

So far I have managed to setup Apache Qpid java broker and connect to it from a Java application using latest JBossTS (Narayana 5.0.0.M1) as standalone JTA. Basic tests showed that messages successfully appear in a queue when I commit TX and are properly ignored when I rollback. But I'm not sure whether this proves that I can safely use Qpid client in CMT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a linkedin AMQP Group where it's said:

"There started a sub spec of AMQP 1.0 concerning distributed tx which was heavily influenced by Microsoft. Totally incompatible with JTA."

That might be reason why you (and me too) haven't found any example.

source: https://www.linkedin.com/groups/AMQP-JTA-1369617.S.5995685814774882304?trk=groups_most_popular-0-b-ttl&goback=%2Egmp_1369617